# How to extract CSV field and pass it to another command

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that makes an API request that returns the result in CSV format.
I want to extract only the "id" value from the first line(It will always be the same in the rest of the lines) and then pass it to wget command (for example wget http://test.com/$id)

Current bash script:

```
req = curl -k -d '{"returnFormat":"csv","eventid":"2"}' -H "Authorization: xxx" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST https://test.api/restSearch
```

The outputs:

```
id,category,type,value,comment,date,subject_tag
1357,"activity","domain","dodskj.com","comment",1547034584,"kill-chain"
1357,"activity","ip-dst","8.8.6.6","comment example",1547034600,"maec-mal""
```

According to this example, I want to extract the value "1357" into a variable and send it to the wget command or any other command.

Comment: If any of the fields can contain a quoted comma, you need to use a real CSV parser; use a language that already has one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cut` command ... in this case:

```
curl <params> | cut -d, -f1
```

or alternatively `awk`:

```
curl <params> | awk -F, '{print $1}'
```

For your specific example, if you only want the second line you can use:

```
curl <param> | awk -F, 'NR == 2 {print $1}'
```

If you want to select a line based on a particular field then:

```
curl <param> | awk -F, '$4 == "dodskj.com" {print $1}'
```

(you can match regular expressions using `~` operator in place of `==`)

You can also break after the first match with `exit`:

```
curl <param> | awk -F, '$4 == "dodskj.com" {print $1; exit}'
```

Then you can encapsulate the whole lot in `$()` to assign to a variable ...

```
VAR=$(curl ... | awk ...)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your csv into `awk`.

```
req=$(<prev_cmd> | awk -F, 'NR==2{print $1}')
```

`-F,` tells `awk` that fields are comma-delimited.
`NR==2` will run the script in braces only for the second row.
`print $1` will print the first field.

`$(...)` performs [*command substitution*](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

Note: remember no spaces between variable assignments.